# How to get multiple records in the main model based on an array from a nested serializer?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have next code:

models.py

```
class tbox(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField("box", max_length=15)
        status = models.CharField("status box", max_length=50)


class tbox_move(models.Model):
        tbox = models.ForeignKey('api.tbox',related_name='tbox_moves', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        discription = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
                return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import tbox, tbox_move

class tboxSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, write_only=False)
        class Meta:
                model = tbox
                fields = ['id', 'name', 'status']
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
                print("Updade in serializer TBOX")


class tbox_moveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        tbox_moves = tboxSerializer(many=True)
        class Meta:
                model = tbox_move
                fields = ['tbox_moves', 'discription']

        def create(self, validated_data):
                tboxs_data = validated_data.pop('tbox_moves')
                for tbox_data in tboxs_data:
                        tbox_id = tbox_data.get("id", None)
                        if tbox_id is None:
                                print("requare BOX ID")
                        id_tbox = tbox.objects.filter(id=tbox_id).update(**tbox_data)
                        tbox_m = tbox_move.objects.create(tbox=tbox_id, **validated_data)
                return tbox_m
```

I send next request POST json:

```
{
    "tbox_moves" : [
       {"id" : 3, "id_test" : 1, "name" : "name_box1", "status": "block"},
       {"id" : 1, "id_test" : 1, "name" : "name_box2", "status": "block"}
    ],
    "description": "collective data"
}
```

I want to get the following result.

1. Create multiple records in the model equal to the number in the nested serializer
   Example tbox_move model:

| ID | discription | tbox_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | collective data | 3 |
| 11 | collective data | 1 |

2. I want update status in the nested model tbox from enable to block

How this create?

Comment: `tbox_moves = tboxSerializer(many=True)` -- This field is about tbox but the name is tbox_moves. That's confusing

Comment: `tbox_move.objects.create(tbox=tbox_id, **validated_data)` -- This is inside the for loop. Just confirming you create one tbox per tbox move?

Comment: yes it is in loop, because if I look at this example, I need to create 2 records in tbox_move and update the status of two records in tbox. If create tbox_move outside loop for i get only 1 record in tbox_move.

Comment: Right ok. I think your serializer should work. If not, what errors are you getting? Or what is not working?

Comment: tbox_move.objects.create(tbox=tbox_id, **validated_data)
in value null, null

Comment: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "tbox_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (50, null, null).

Comment: Did you send tbox_moves without "id"?